# Regex to Split String is not working well for "[,，.\\s]" in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I hope to split a String into groups by"," or"，"(Chinese comma) or "." or any blank char(like white space or "\n").

I am new to regex.
I write the below test case:

```
    String str2="word1 , word2，,word3.word4 word5";
    String[] formated=str2.split("[,，.\\s]");
    for(int i=0;i<formated.length;i++){
        System.out.println("i="+i+ "   "+formated[i]);
    }
```

The out put is:

```
i=0   word1
i=1   
i=2   
i=3   word2
i=4   
i=5   word3
i=6   word4
i=7   word5
```

Why it is not working when the sign comes together? Is it something more I should do to make it to be a whole sign to split when something like ",，"comes together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try. You need to add `+` to match one or more.

```
[,，.\s]+
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH2gW1/5)

---

### [Quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Quantifiers allow you to specify the **`number of occurrences`** to match against. If you uses `x+` then the pattern tries to matches `x` as many as possible.

```
word1 , word2，,word3.word4 word5
     ^^^------All three characters are matched at a time

word1 , word2，,word3.word4 word5
             ^^------both characters are matched at a time
```

If you don't uses `+` then only single character is used to split the string.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you please also help to explain if I do not add "+", how it works different from the one with "+". Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Use following `regExp` to `split` as it will allow you to split from one or more characters specified in `[]`

```
[,，.\\s]+
```

- `[]` Matches *any single character* from `String` within the bracketed list
- `+` Matches one or more occurrences.

Without `+` it will spilt like this

```
word1 , word2，,word3.word4 word5
     ^^^     ^^^     ^     ^
     123     456     7     8
```

So you will have total `8 String` after split but when you add `plus`, it will count `123` and `456` as single one because now your regExp is able to match one or more occurrences of characters.